# How to check whether Java installed or not through shell script on Ubuntu?

Tags: shell

I have written one shell script to check whether Java is installed in a system or not.

Now I want to have a logic like this:

- If Java is not installed or not found in a system then it will ask the user do you want to install Java
- If java is already installed then it will show Java is already installed in your system

Here is my code:

```
(update-java-alternatives -l | \
grep oracle | \
awk '{system(""$3"/bin/java -version 2>&1 | \
grep \"java version\"")}') | \
awk -F\" '{print $1}''{print $2}' 

read -p "Continue (y/n)?" choice
case "$choice" in 
  y|Y ) echo "$(tput setaf 1) $(tput setab 7)Adding PPA$(tput sgr 0)"
        sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
        echo "$(tput setaf 1)$(tput setab 7)updating repositories$(tput sgr 0)"
        sudo apt-get update
        sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
        echo "$(tput setaf 1)$(tput setab 7)instaling software-properties-common$(tput sgr 0)"
        sudo apt-get install software-properties-common ;;
  n|N ) echo "no" ;;
    * ) echo "invalid" ;;
esac
```

Comment: This checks only for oracle-java, not for the open-jdk.

Comment: Code should be included **in the question itself** as text, not an image; select that text and click the `{}` button to apply formatting. See [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122)

Comment: ok but i want to make my code like this if oracle-java is not installed or not found in a system then it will ask the user do you want to install java? and if java is already installed then it will show java is already installed in your system

Comment: ...what are you trying to do with the `grep | awk '{system(...)}'` code? Generally speaking, using `system()` in awk is a bad idea, and should be replaced with native-bash primitives. (bash doesn't parse variable expansion results as code, but understands that they're only data; `system()` makes no distinction in terms of where data comes from, which has security implications: Expanding a variable in shell won't perform a command substitution unless you're using `eval` or passing it to `sh` or `ssh`; performing a replacement in a string passed to `system()` *will*).

Comment: If the reason you're using `awk` there is to break the output from `update-java-alternatives -l` down into lines, see [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for guidance

Comment: btw, you need to keep four-space indents on all your code in the question -- otherwise it won't be syntax-highlighted.